# Why is the curve undefined in GeoGebra?

Tags: geogebra

I tried to plot this equation in 3d (using GeoGebra), but got "undefined" as output.

[image: equation]

The numerator and denominator separately produces a plot however.

Even [Wolfram Alpha gives me a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+%28x%5E2+%2B+y+%5E+2%29%2F%28xy%2B1%29&x=0&y=0), however it's not interactive. 
I am not sure if my intuition is incorrect, or it is a bug in GeoGebra?

Answer (score 1):

I had to click on the GeoGebra 3d Grapher button several times in order to get to the 3d Grapher screen, but finally I got there by spamming the 3d Grapher button and it showed a 3d grid with the x, y and z axes in red, green and blue. When you see a screen that looks like the below screenshot you are ready to start plotting.

[image]

I typed this equation in the input box manually, because it is easier to type from the keyboard than by using GeoGebra's online keyboard.

```
z = (x**2+y**2)/(x*y)+1
```

GeoGebra makes automatic interactive changes to the output plot and the formatting of the input text as you type. This is the plot of `z = (x**2+y**2)/(x*y)+1`

[image]

The output plot is superimposed over the original x, y and z axes. The input text next to the light green circle in the input text box changed so fast as I typed it that there wasn't time to get a screenshot of the original unformatted input text.

Comment: My reply to your question if there is a bug in the GeoGebra software is opinion based so I am answering this part of your question in the comments section. GeoGebra is interactive therefore it changes as you type, but why does it have to change so fast? The fast changes make it difficult to edit my input text, so if I make a mistake I have to delete what I typed and retype the entire equation.